# Angular 6 Client Login Issue

Tags: angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have angular 6 app which use **angular-oauth2-oidc(4.0.2)** client lib for authentication and **identity server4** is uses for authentication.

I got an issue when user logged-In and then logged-out then user will bookmark logged-out url for later use .In this case it bookmarks with the id_token,state ,nonce etc.

But later he tries to log in the system i get an error

```
angular-oauth2-oidc.js:1155 validating access_token failed. 
 wrong state/nonce. 6IInrKyhEZNu9fkWQIMteAVhMlgj1hCa8vkrZvZV VEJve05brl8VhbZSVsoYHQUhd6tKRcoWi3DTNHXG

Error: Uncaught (in promise): OAuthErrorEvent:
 {"type":"invalid_nonce_in_state","reason":null,"params":null}
```

There are different resources but no strait forward fix for this as i checked.I tried different scenarios but no luck for solution.

Can any one do any help on this

Thanks in advance

While i was debugging client library i saw the nonceInState property is replaced by state property in this line of code

[nonce is replaced by state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deS3X.png)

and later it fails from here

[Validation firs from this place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esOZW.png)

Hope any one can give me a support on this.

Comment: Did you fix your problem? I'm having the same issue.